# Realm Overrides Object in DB

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, realm

I am currently getting my feet wet with Kotlin, RealmDB, and Android Development in Android Studio.

Whenever I try to insert a new Account Realm-object into database via Save Button, it seems that it erases the last saved object and inserts the new one, thus only one object is within the database per user. I have debugged this flow and the query only returns one object from result set.

```
    private lateinit var firebaseUser:FirebaseUser
    private lateinit var firebaseAuth:FirebaseAuth

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?){

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.my_layout)

        //init views
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()
        titleED = findViewById(R.id.title_edit_text)
        descED = findViewById(R.id.desc_edit_text)
        saveAccountBtn = findViewById(R.id.saveAccountBtn)

        savePsswdBtn.setOnClickListener {
            addAccountToDB()
        }
    }

    private fun addAccountToDB(){

        try{

            realm.beginTransaction()

            firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
            firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.currentUser!!

            val account  = Account()
            account.id = //generatesID()
            account.title = titleED.text.toString()
            account.desc = descED.text.toString()
            account.userID = firebaseUser.uid

            //copy to DB
            realm.insertOrUpdate(account)
            realm.commitTransaction()

            Toast.makeText(this, "Success!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            startActivity(Intent(this, InitialActivity::class.java))
            finish()

        }catch (ex:Exception){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Failed $ex ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
```

Object class

```
open class Account (

    @PrimaryKey
    var id:Int?=null,
    var title:String?=null,
    var desc:String?=null,
    var userID:String?=null

) :
```

Is my use of Realm above somehow cleansing user's db and saving new object? I played around with the Account's primary key (the account.id member) to see if that was affecting it but same problem persists. Also alternated between Realm's .insertOrUpdate() and .copyToRealmOrUpdate().

Comment: Hi Panda. How is this question related to Firebase?

Comment: Not very much, I chose to tag in case I was overlooking something when I get uid information from Firebase User (i.e., this line: `account.userID = firebaseUser.uid`) that might cause the error presented here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I was refactoring the piece that saves account into database, I moved the Primary Key assignment there as well, and somehow that allowed me to add more Objects.